# How to fix 'Cannot find 'Map' Do you need to change your target library?'

Tags: typescript

I'm learning TypeScript right now and I have an issue  with compiling my TS file to JS file.
After the command 'tsc test.ts', some errors occur.

I have tried to change the "target:" to "es6" but it didn't take any effect. I have also added "es6" to the "lib":[] but it also didn't work.

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom",
      "es6"
    ]
  }
}
```

node_modules/@types/selenium-webdriver/remote.d.ts:139:29 - error TS2583: Cannot find name 'Map'. Do you need to change your target library? Try changing the
`lib` compiler option to es2015 or later.

139         setEnvironment(env: Map | {[name: string]: string} | null): this;

Comment: I can't reproduce this issue.  How sure are you that `tsc` is using your `tsconfig.json` file in its build?

Comment: btw, remove all the extra stuff, you don't need `baseUrl` and `typeRoots`